# How to show hide particular control of partialView on some condition on pageLoad using asp.net mvc4 razor?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I tried with ViewBag but no use, it gives me error as:

> 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL'

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you check you your condition in controller itself and get result there. or you are thinking to do it from jQuery. Reply and i can tell the solution accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Vinay for your response!                                 Yes,i can check condition in controller,here condition depends on parameter value.I want hide and show the controls just for first time after that on some event i have written code to hide n show the same.it will be better if we can do it from jQuery.

Comment: this is just like email managment system,where i want to manage 'New','Send','Cancel','Forword' and 'Reply' button on InBox and OutBox list

Comment: so have you tried the approach suggested by me, setting the display property from the temp data.

Comment: Vinay will you pls let me know how to set Html.Raw(TempData["DisplayValue"]) to html button?

Comment: Any one know how to set Html.Raw(TempData["DisplayValue"]) to html button?means to <input type="button"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can check the Condition in the controller than you can send a value in tempdata like

```
public Action SomeControllerMethod()
{
  TempData["DisplayValue"] = @"""Display: block""";
  if(somecondition)
  {
    TempData["DisplayValue"] = @"""Display: none""";
  }
  return View();
}
```

and we can use this Tempdata to set the disply property in the view
ex:

```
Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.SomeProperty, new {@style=Html.Raw(TempData["DisplayValue"])});
```